# Android http client protocol exception

Tags: android, image, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am developing small android application in which i tried to send simple image to my server. My problem is that when i tried to add header content-length it gives me error http client protocol exception. My code structure looks like ..

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String message;
    HttpPut p = new HttpPut("https://abc.com");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    try {
        int size = data.length;
        p.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));

        p.setHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(data.length));
        //p.setHeader("Content-Length", "0");
        //p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
        if (resp != null)
        {
            if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
            {

            }
        }

        Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    try {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "before exception "+result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "inside catch ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Am I doing the right thing? How to solve this problem. Need help. Thank you.

My error trace looks like

```
03-16 10:02:47.663: W/System.err(5804): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at com.example.profileimage.ImageUpload$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(ImageUpload.java:243)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at com.example.profileimage.ImageUpload$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(ImageUpload.java:1)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-16 10:02:47.687: W/System.err(5804): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:70)
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-16 10:02:47.695: W/System.err(5804):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace from the log cat ?

Comment: Here is your error "Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present". Remove the setHeader(), you don't need it.

Comment: HttpPut sets Content-Length based on the Entity you include. No reason to do it by hand.

Comment: yeah that's solve my problem. thank you

Comment: Could you please mark your post as solved ?

Comment: How to mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2):

To get it off the unanswered questions list:

---

The error is

> "Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: `Content-Length` header already present".

Remove the setHeader(), you don't need it - HttpPut sets `Content-Length` based on the Entity you include. No reason to do it by hand.

Comment: I know the question was posted long time ago, but this answer is correct. Please accept it